# Having trouble implementing Microsoft Graph Java SDK to list licenses assigned to user

Tags: java, charts, licensing, azure-java-sdk, azure-identity

I'm currently working on integrating Microsoft Graph APIs into my Java application to retrieve license details for users in my Microsoft 365 tenant. I referred to the official Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-licensedetails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java) to understand the usage of the Microsoft Graph Java SDK for this purpose. However, despite following the provided guidance, I'm encountering difficulties in implementing the solution within my Java codebase.

**Context:**

- I'm utilizing the Microsoft Graph Java SDK to interact with Microsoft 365 APIs.
- Specifically, I'm referring to the documentation for listing license details for a user [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-licensedetails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java).
- My authentication setup and GraphServiceClient instantiation are already in place, following the documentation.

**Issue:** The code snippet provided in the documentation is as follows:

```java
// Code snippets are only available for the latest version. Current version is 6.x

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

LicenseDetailsCollectionResponse result = graphClient.users().byUserId("{user-id}").licenseDetails().get();
```

I've attempted to integrate this code into my Java application. While I can successfully query the Microsoft Graph API using tools like Postman, I'm unable to replicate the functionality within my Java codebase.

**Expectation:** I'm seeking assistance in understanding and resolving the following:

1. How can I properly configure the `requestAdapter` required for initializing the `GraphServiceClient` instance in Java?
2. Are there any additional configurations or dependencies required to make the Microsoft Graph Java SDK work seamlessly within a Java application?

I appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully retrieve license details for users using the Microsoft Graph Java SDK within my Java application.